# An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net

the error message:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   test_login.dll but was not handled in user code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace test_login
{
    public partial class home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            long user_id = (long)(Session["user_id"]);

            if (Session["user_id"] == null) { Response.Redirect("login.aspx"); return; }
            DBEntities ctx = new DBEntities();
            user user = ctx.users.First(u => u.user_id == user_id);
            lblOwnerName.Text = user.user_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's nice. Did you have a question?

Comment: Look at `Session["user_id"]` in the debugger, what is it's type? Cast to that and handle the case that it's `null` beforehand.

Comment: When asking a question you should try to be more explicit about what your question is and in addition if you have an exception like here you should be clear on what line it is being thrown. It is possible to make guesses about which line it is on and what your question is but the clearer you make it the better for those trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on not so much information I can see one possible issue:

1.Session is NULL in `Session["user_id"]`
It is allways recommended to check wether your session still exists and use a safe cast:

```
if (Session["user_id"] == null)
{
    // session not exists
}
else
{
    long user_id;
    if(!long.TryParse(Session["user_id"].ToString(), out user_id))
    {
       // Handle sitiation if it is not possible to cast
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `Session["user_id"]` is a `string` or whatever? Also, your second point would cause a compiler error not a runtime exception.

Comment: @TimSchmelter. I am not sure but I guess Session["yourKey"] always returns an object so It recommended to use always a safe cast as well. Next to that. Second point you are right. I removed that part

Comment: No, you can store what you want in the `Session` since it's stored in server memory. `Session["user_id"]` returns an `object`. That's also the reason why your `TryParse` currently doesn't compile.

Comment: @hwcverwe `Session["yourKey"]` can be any object but `long.TryParse()` only accepts string